# Where does keytool command logs?

Tags: logs, java

I want to know in which file the keytool command logs all the information.

i.e., when I execute the below command:-

```
keytool -import -file ca-certificate.cer -alias sample -keystore /root/keystore.jks
```

I couldn't find any log information. I also want to add log information for any certificate imports.

Answer (score 1):

[keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html) does not log information; it only writes to the standard output and standard error.  Its documentation lists several cases where it will use one or the other, and does not mention logging.